# How to create dict using csv file with first row as keys

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'd like to create a list of dictionaries reading from a large csv file that uses the entries from the first row as keys. for example, test.csv

```
Header1, Header2, Header3
A,       1,       10
B,       2,       20
C,       3,       30
```

The resulting dict would look like:

```
MyList = [{'Header1': A, 'Header2': 1, 'Header3: 10}, {'Header1': B,     'Header2': 2, 'Header3: 20}, {'Header1': C, 'Header2': 3, 'Header3: 30}]
```

I know how to read a file, and think maybe a defaultdict from collections might be a good way, but can't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is exactly what [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) was made for.

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

For the `data.csv` containing:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3
A,1,10
B,2,20
C,3,30
```

It prints:

```
{'Header2': '1', 'Header3': '10', 'Header1': 'A'}
{'Header2': '2', 'Header3': '20', 'Header1': 'B'}
{'Header2': '3', 'Header3': '30', 'Header1': 'C'}
```

Comment: Thanks, we didn't learn that one in Python training last week.. i was using csv.reader but couldn't iterate through the fields properly.